# Tomcat log pattern %b vs %B

Tags: tomcat, logging

I'm parsing the tomcat's access log, and I can't see what's the difference between these two? 
and the 'Bytes sent' means tomcat send to client, or client send to tomcat?
Please help me understand, thanks!

```
%b - Bytes sent, excluding HTTP headers, or '-' if zero
%B - Bytes sent, excluding HTTP headers
```

> [Tomcat 8 - Access Log Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the number of the bytes that Tomcat sends to client .It only count the response body but excluding the headers.

The difference is that for an empty response body (i.e. 0 bytes) :

- `%b` will print out `-`
- `%B` will print out `0`

They are the same for non-empty response body.